# Set text to EditText in a different layout file

Tags: android, android-edittext

How can I update the `editText` field with a button when the button and the `editText` are on different layouts and classes?

I have a `mainActivity` class and layout but I wand to add this function to an intent (by clicking the save button update main_activity layout). I tried by calling the `saveDegrees` method `onClick` in the intent class but that didn't work.

After that I want to go back to the `main_activity` layout. My `saveDegrees` code is this:

```
public void saveDegrees(View view) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View activityView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
    mCompassEditText = (EditText) activityView.findViewById(
        R.id.compass_edit_text);
    mCompassEditText.setText(toString().valueOf(currentDegree));
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that shows both Activity classes and how you start each activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access an activity from another activity. Instead, you should send the data back to the first activity. You can do this by starting the second activity with `startActivityForResult()` rather than `startActivity()`. The second activity sets the result before finishing. The first activity receives the result in `onActivityResult()` and changes its own views. See [How to manage `startActivityForResult` on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-startactivityforresult-on-android) for more details.